# How to parametrize piecewise regression coefficient to represent the slope for the following interval (instead of the change in the slope)

Tags: r, spline, non-linear-regression, piecewise

Consider the following dataset

```
Quantity <- c(25,39,45,57,70,85,89,100,110,124,137,150,177)
Sales <- c(1000,1250,2600,3000,3500,4500,5000,4700,4405,4000,3730,3400,3300)
df <- data.frame(Quantity,Sales)
df
```

Plotting the data, the distribution of observations is clearly non-linear, but presents a likely breaking-point around Quantity = 89 (I skip the plot here). Therefore, I built a joint piecewise linear model as follows

```
df$Xbar <- ifelse(df$Quantity>89,1,0)
df$diff <- df$Quantity - 89

reg <- lm(Sales ~ Quantity + I(Xbar * (Quantity - 89)), data = df)
summary(reg)
```

or simply

```
df$X <- df$diff*df$Xbar

reg <- lm(Sales ~ Quantity + X, data = df)
summary(reg)
```

However, according to this parametrization, the coefficient of X represents the change in the slope from the preceding interval.

How can I parametrize the relevant coefficient to rather represent the slope for the second interval?

I did some research but I was unable to find the desired specification, apart from some automatization in stata (see the voice 'marginal' here https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmkspline.pdf).

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Acknowledgement:
the workable example is retrieved from 
https://towardsdatascience.com/unraveling-spline-regression-in-r-937626bc3d96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to use a logical variable `is.right` which is TRUE for the points to the right of 89 and FALSE otherwise.

From the the output shown 60.88 is the slope to the left of 89 and -19.97 is the slope to the right.  The lines intersect at Quantity = 89, Sales = 4817.30.

```
is.right <- df$Quantity > 89
fm <- lm(Sales ~ diff : is.right, df)

fm
## Call:
## lm(formula = Sales ~ diff:is.right, data = df)
##
## Coefficients:
##        (Intercept)  diff:is.rightFALSE   diff:is.rightTRUE  
##            4817.30               60.88              -19.97
```

### Alternatives

Alternately if you want to use `Xbar` from the question do it this way. It gives the same coefficients as `fm`.

```
fm2 <- lm(Sales ~ diff : factor(Xbar), df)
```

or

```
fm3 <- lm(Sales ~ I(Xbar * diff) + I((1 - Xbar) * diff), df)
```

### Double check with nls

We can double check these using `nls` with the following formulation which makes use of the fact that if we extend both lines the one to use at any Quantity is the lower of the two.

```
st <- list(a = 0, b1 = 1, b2 = -1)
fm4 <- nls(Sales ~ a + pmin(b1 * (Quantity - 89), b2 * (Quantity - 89)), start = st)
fm4
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: Sales ~ a + pmin(b1 * (Quantity - 89), b2 * (Quantity - 89))
##    data: parent.frame()
##       a      b1      b2 
## 4817.30   60.88  -19.97 
## residual sum-of-squares: 713120
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.285e-09
```

This would also work:

```
fm5 <- nls(Sales ~ a + ifelse(Quantity > 89, b2, b1) * diff, df, start = st)
```

### Plot

Here is a plot:

```
plot(Sales ~ Quantity, df)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ Quantity, df)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Model matrix

And here is the model matrix for the linear regression:

```
> model.matrix(fm)
   (Intercept) diff:is.rightFALSE diff:is.rightTRUE
1            1                -64                 0
2            1                -50                 0
3            1                -44                 0
4            1                -32                 0
5            1                -19                 0
6            1                 -4                 0
7            1                  0                 0
8            1                  0                11
9            1                  0                21
10           1                  0                35
11           1                  0                48
12           1                  0                61
13           1                  0                88
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the breakpoints, then you almost have the model, it should be:

```
fit=lm(Sales ~ Quantity + Xbar + Quantity:Xbar,data=df)
```

Because if you don't introduce a new intercept (Xbar), it will start from the intercept already in the model, which will not work. We can plot it:

```
plot(df$Quantity,df$Sales)
newdata = data.frame(Quantity=seq(40,200,by=5))
newdata$Xbar= ifelse(newdata$Quantity>89,1,0)
lines(newdata$Quantity,predict(fit,newdata))
```

[image]

The coefficients are:

```
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Sales ~ Quantity * Xbar, data = df)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-527.9 -132.2  -15.1  148.1  464.7 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -545.435    327.977  -1.663    0.131    
Quantity        59.572      5.746  10.367 2.65e-06 ***
Xbar          7227.288    585.933  12.335 6.09e-07 ***
Quantity:Xbar  -80.133      6.856 -11.688 9.64e-07 ***
```

And the coefficient of the 2nd slope is 59.572+(-80.133) = -20.561